# Run a docker container from an existing container using docker-py

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerpy, docker-in-docker

I have a Docker container which runs a Flask application. When Flask receives and http request, I would like to trigger the execution of a **new ephemeral Docker container** which shutdowns once it completes what it has to do.

I have read Docker-in-Docker should be avoided so this new container should be run as a **sibling container** on my host and not within the Flask container.

What would be the solution to do this with [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io)?

Comment: What have you tried already?  Do you have some sample code and something like a `docker-compose.yml` or a `docker run` command for the main service you can share?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet as I'm not very sure how to start on this. I'll update my answer with what I have in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question. Here is a complete setup which works.
In one folder, create the following files:

- requirements.txt
- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- api.py

**requirements.txt**

```
docker==3.5.0
flask==1.0.2
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.7


# Project files
ARG PROJECT_DIR=/srv/api
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_DIR
WORKDIR $PROJECT_DIR
COPY requirements.txt ./

# Install Python dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

**docker-compose.yml**

Make sure to mount docker.sock in volumes as mentioned in the previous answer above.

```
version: '3'
services:
  api:
    container_name: test
    restart: always
    image: test
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      - ./:/srv/api/
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      FLASK_APP: api.py
    command: ["flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

**api.py**

```
from flask import Flask
import docker
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello():
    client = docker.from_env()
    client.containers.run('alpine', 'echo hello world', detach=True, remove=True)
    return "Hello World!"
```

Then open your browser and navigate to `http://0.0.0.0:5000/`

It will trigger the execution of the alpine container. If you don't already have the alpine image, it will take a bit of time the first time because Docker will automatically download the image.

The arguments `detach=True` allows to execute the container asynchronously so that Flask does not wait for the end of the process before returning its response.

The argument `remove=True` indicates Docker to remove the container once its execution is completed.

Answer (score 10):

we are doing stuff like this by mounting `docker.sock` as shared volume between the host machine and the container. This allows the container sending commands to the machine such as docker run

this is an example from our CI system:

```
 volumes:
 - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: I read about this indeed but would mounting docker socket in my Flask container be enough to run a sibling container with docker-py?

Comment: Yes, with this you can control docker as if you're on the host

Comment: (...and remember that you can control the host as any other user that can run Docker commands can.)